# Is there a way to create a function that can learn and forget moves similar to pokemon?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm coding a text-based game that lets the player learn different abilities as the game progresses. Similar to pokemon, I want the player to have the ability to learn and forget moves.

When in battle, I want to display the name of the ability and what it does in numeric order. My problem is that if a new move if learned and replaces another ability, then I don't know how to change the ability's function. This sounds very confusing, so here is a general idea of what it looks like.

```py
ability_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for index, value in enumerate(ability_list, 1):
    print("{}) {}".format(index, value))
ability_option = input(">>>")

if ability_option == "1" or ability_option.lower() == "a":
    #Does the ability
    #same thing for the other 3 abilities
```

Now, let's say `a` in the ability list was changed to something else like `f`, how would I make it so that if `ability_option` were `1`, it would change the function of it?

Comment: You can change your list to a dict, where the keys are the abilities and their values are the matching functions to execute the ability

Answer (score 0):

So you need to map your functions to a dictionary. Then you will be able to change them at will. Something like this:

```
def some_func(x):
    print(f'I am in some_func: {x}')


def foo(y):
    print(f'This is foo: {y}')


def bar():
    print('I am bar, I have no variable.')


func_map = {
    '1': some_func,
    '2': foo
}


func_map['1']('yay!')
func_map['2']('boo!!!')

func_map['2'] = bar

func_map['2']()
```

This will produce the output:

```
I am in some_func: yay!
This is foo: boo!!!
I am bar, I have no variable.
```